# Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine "abc" failed

Tags: c#, .net, exception, tfs, tfs-workitem

Please help me out. its showing error in 2nd line.

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://abc..."));
WorkItemStore  wiStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();  //error here          
return wiStore.Projects;
```

error: Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine 'abc' failed. The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. This may be because the remote computer does not exist or a firewall may be preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance.

Comment: have you tried writing IP instead?

Comment: yes , still showing same error . i am able to run the whole app using F5 but while debugging its showing error.

Comment: you are trying to debug service itself which is located in the other computer, it is why you are getting that error. Do you really want to debug service? Or something else?

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable remote debugging in the remote server using msvsmon.exe. Please have a look at the following post for the same

http://www.sadev.co.za/content/how-debug-workflow-assemblies-and-plug-ins-mscrm-40